# CSS wiggle/shake effect

Tags: css, animation

The effect I am intend to do: 
-wiggle a few times and stop wiggling. Do this behaviour periodically until mouse is hover. 
-on hover, wiggle motion stops completely. 
-all transition are smooth out. 
I tried with -webkit-animation keyframes, but using -webkit-animation-timing-function to ease out the transition when the mouse is hovered didn t work. 
Also, i am lost on how to achieve the period motion of: wiggle, stop, and wiggle again. 
I would appreciate if you could point out in the right directions.

Comment: Check out "Animate.css", it's a CSS framework for animations created by Dan Eden. Craig Dennis expanded on that framework with a jquery plugin to allow you to easily tie in star/stop hooks and delays between animations.  Using the two in conjunction should allow you to achieve the wiggle / stop / wiggle some more feature you want.

Comment: animate.css is actually very good and offers great flexibility. I may just study their code to get the basic principles. thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Here is a simple wiggle animation that stops when you hover over it.

In order to achieve a delay between wiggles, you can just include an "empty chunk" of the animation... that is, a period during which nothing changes. In my example, nothing changes between the 0% and 80% mark, and the "wiggle" only occurs in the last 20% (which ends up coming out to half a second).

```css
@keyframes wiggle {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   80% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   85% { transform: rotate(5deg); }
   95% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

h1.wiggle {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: wiggle 2.5s infinite;
}

h1.wiggle:hover {
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wiggle">
  wiggle, wiggle
</h1>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't account for "easing" back into the un-wiggled state if you hover over it mid-animation. Doing so might require a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: thank you! it s still solves one part of my problem which was having control over the periodicity of the animation. I thought css would be enough to easing the animation. How would you do in javascript?

Comment: @SangamChouchan i thought CSS would be enough too. i thought adding `transition: transform 0.5s` to the `h1.wiggle` class would cause it to ease out of the animation, but it doesn't seem to be working. i'm experimenting with a javascript solution now.

Answer (score 15):

Try one of the following:

```
.class:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/

or
Add This to your Script : `<link type="text/css"  href="https://rawgit.com/elrumordelaluz/csshake/master/dist/csshake.min.css"></link>`

And Add a class to the element you want to shake

Full Documentation here: https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/