# IE11 - CSS wiggle animation not moving

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div that I am trying to make wiggle, but it does not seem to be working in IE 11. The div wiggles in Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Firefox, and Opera. Reading about the issue I thought it might be the vendor specific prefixes so I added those, but I still have no luck. My css is as follows:

```
.myClass{
     -webkit-animation: wiggle infinite 2s alternate;
     -moz-animation: wiggle infinite 2s alternate;
     -ms-animation: wiggle infinite 2s alternate;
     -o-animation:wiggle infinite 2s alternate;
      animation: wiggle infinite 2s alternate;
      transform-origin: bottom;
    }    


@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
}

@-ms-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes wiggle {

  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
}


@keyframes wiggle {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(1deg);}
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong - but I'm pretty sure there's no such thing as `-ms-animation`... where did you get it from?

Comment: refer to this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132700/css-wiggle-shake-effect

Comment: @SumitPatel I tried adding the attributes in that post, but no luck